# Android App not getting installed on device

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am working on a sample android app to learn more about android. Strangely, the app doesn't get installed on my Motorola Xoom.

Please note the app runs fine on the device. But when I see the app list on the device I can't find my app.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mycamapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mycamapp.CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have tried some other sample apps(hello world!! kind of examples) and they get installed on my device just fine.

I do not see any apk install message when I run from eclipse. Can anyone advise, what is going wrong with the app?

Comment: `<data android:mimeType="image/*"` why do you have this on your launcher activity filter?  The only way another app (like the launcher) can launch you is to pass an image, which the launcher will not be doing.  You should have a separate filter for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the issue is with the `<intent-filter>` of your `CameraActivity`. 
All present elements have to match, and I guess the launcher does not have a image mimeType in its intents ;)

Remove the `<data>` element from your `<intent-filter>`, or move it to another one, and the icon should appear. You can have several intent filters for the same activity.

Source: [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs)